# jquery class selector capture only the clicked element within the class

Tags: jquery

Here's the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/9fnh6ffy/

Here's the HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" class="new-answer">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box">
</div>

<p><a href="#" class="new-answer">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box">
</div>

<p><a href="#" class="new-answer">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box">
</div>
```

I want whenever the `.new-answer` link is clicked, the corresponding `.answer-box` underneath it is opened. However I don't want to select it relatively such as using `$(this).parents('p').next().toggle` because I don't want to get into problem later debugging if I change the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you don't want dom relationship to be used another approach could be is to use a attribute value. For example you can use a `data-id` attribute where you specify a number, where the same number will be associated to the related `new-answer` and `answer-box` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.new-answer').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.answer-box[data-id="' + id + '"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.answer-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="new-answer" data-id="1">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box" data-id="1"></div>

<p><a href="#" class="new-answer" data-id="2">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box" data-id="2"></div>

<p><a href="#" class="new-answer" data-id="3">New answer</a></p>
<div class="answer-box" data-id="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse to parent `p` element and then target immediate next sibling:

```
$(this).parent().next().toggle();
```

### Working Demo

**Update:**
As the Dom structure may vary:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.answer-box').first().toggle();
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Is there any other way besides using that? I mentioned in my post that's exactly what I want to avoid. The reason is because I'm using blade templating, and the current DOM is only for when `$answer <= 1`. However, later as the user post more answers, I would put another DOM in between such as `.other-answers` div

Comment: can you share that DOM??

Comment: Sure. something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/csmys1mm/1/ . Notice the first `.new-answer` link is now not opening the div underneath it when it's clicked